# Loop in a function

Tags: r, function, for-loop, matrix, nonlinear-functions

Package for Jacobian matrix

```
install.packages('pracma')
library('pracma')
```

Suppose I have the following set of non linear functions

```
f <- function(beta) c(y[1]*beta[1]+z[1]*1/beta[2],
                      y[2]*beta[1]+z[2]*1/beta[2],
                      :   :     :    :
                    y[i]*beta[1]^2+z[i]*1/beta[2])
```

Now suppose i becomes very large, writing out all functions of i is very time-consuming.

How can I write such a function?
I tried the following:

```
f <- function(beta) cbind(y, z) %*% (c(beta^2,(beta^-1)), ncol = 1, nrow = 2)
```

When I apply this function to construct Jacobian matrix it is not of the format I would like to have

```
y = 1:10
z = 10:19
f <- function(beta) cbind(y, z) %*% matrix(cbind(beta^2,1/beta), ncol = 1, nrow = 2)
jacobian(f, c(1,1))
```

Which gives the correct output for the first column, but not the second:

```
     [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    2   20
 [2,]    4   22
 [3,]    6   24
 [4,]    8   26
 [5,]   10   28
 [6,]   12   30
 [7,]   14   32
 [8,]   16   34
 [9,]   18   36
[10,]   20   38
```

Another try:

```
f <- function(beta) cbind(y, z) %*% cbind(beta^2,1/beta)
jacobian(f, c(1,1))
```

Gives the following results:

```
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    2   20
 [2,]    4   22
 [3,]    6   24
 [4,]    8   26
 [5,]   10   28
 [6,]   12   30
 [7,]   14   32
 [8,]   16   34
 [9,]   18   36
[10,]   20   38
[11,]   -1  -10
[12,]   -2  -11
[13,]   -3  -12
[14,]   -4  -13
[15,]   -5  -14
[16,]   -6  -15
[17,]   -7  -16
[18,]   -8  -17
[19,]   -9  -18
[20,]  -10  -19
```

Where the first 10 observations of the first column and the 11:20 observations of the second column are the once I need.

Does anyone know how to just get these two vectors? Should I create a loop inside the function?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `vectorisation` in R as follows:

```
y <- 1:10
z <- 10:19
beta <- c(1, 1)

f <- function(y, z, beta = c(1, 1)) {
  y * beta[[1]] ** 2 + z * 1 / beta[[2]]
}

f(y, z, beta)
```

```
#> f(y, z, beta)
# [1] 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29
```

### Edit:

Thanks `@Hans W.` for your comment and improvement to my answer. Here is the edit:

```
# define y & z in global working environment:
y <- 1:10
z <- 10:19

# The function:
f <- function(beta) {
  y * beta[[1]] ** 2 + z * 1 / beta[[2]]
}

# Find Jacobian:
pracma::jacobian(f, c(1, 1))
```

```
#       [,1] [,2]
#  [1,]    2  -10
#  [2,]    4  -11
#  [3,]    6  -12
#  [4,]    8  -13
#  [5,]   10  -14
#  [6,]   12  -15
#  [7,]   14  -16
#  [8,]   16  -17
#  [9,]   18  -18
# [10,]   20  -19
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. I think I have not formulated my question correctly. The objective is to generate a function specified in the first line of code. So that I can use that to generate the Jacobian of it. Now creating that function manually uses alot of iterations. Therefore I was looking for an iterative procedure that would automatically create the functions for all values up until i. With what you supplied I do not know how to get the Jacobian.

Comment: In which package is the function `jacobian()`?

Comment: This can be found in the pracma package

Comment: Where the function is structured as follow: jacobian(f, x0, heps = .Machine$double.eps^(1/3), ...), Now f are m functions of n variables. In my case, I need i functions of two variables. Which I am trying to obtain by coding the function

Comment: This solution is correct, though it would be better to write the function
as `f=function(beta) beta[1]^2*y+z/beta[2]`. Then `pracma::jacobian(f,c(1,1))`
will return
        [,1] [,2]
   [1,]    2  -10
   [2,]    4  -11
   ...